# Java's XML parser is too forgiving

Tags: java, xml

I'm writing tests, so I need an XML parser that detects any conceivable deviation from permitted syntax.

This code passes without a complaint despite it contains a `>>`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
String oops = "<xml><oops></oops>></xml>";
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(oops.getBytes());
builder.parse(stream);
```

How do I increase the level of syntax checking? To complain about anything, not just one little `>>` that I can grep for?

(Note that while other readers of this post might be interested in third-party libraries that can do it, I can only use `javax` to prevent runaway dependencies in my project)

Comment: Your example XML is valid, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I think the `>` is just recognized as a raw value of the `<xml>` tag and should be correct XML.

Comment: Your XML is well-formed, and `>` does not have to be escaped there.  See [Simplified XML Escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085) for a concise and fully cited explanation of XML character escaping requirements.

Comment: Aside:  Names (of elements, for example) that begin with `xml` are reserved  for standardization, but this is generally not considered a violation of XML rules of well-formedness.

Comment: Further aside: I find the question rather surprising. In particular, I find it surprising that anyone who is not intimately familiar with the fine detail of the XML spec should attempt this task, let alone imagine that they can do a better job of it than mature XML parsers like the one in the JDK. I also find it rather surprising that anyone would prefer to write code themselves rather than use a third party library because of "runaway dependencies": these days, surely, we construct software from reusable components?

Comment: answering Michael Kay - I use automated tests to make sure my XHTML follows many more rules than a mere standard. For example, I don't permit '<output></output>` because that means the entire field should either have `N/A` or should go away

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to configure a (properly implemented) XML parser to reject the unwanted `>` in your example.  A `>` is allowed at that point according to the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax):

> The right angle bracket (`>`) **may** be represented using the string "`&gt;`", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either "`&gt;`" or a character reference when it appears in the string "`]]>`" in content, when that string is not marking the end of a `CDATA` section.

So if you wanted to detect the extraneous `>` you would need to do some extra checking of element content.

<sup>This would be difficult if you wanted / needed to distinguish between (accidental) `>` characters and (intentional) `&gt;` in the element content.  An XML parser will normalize them to `>` during parsing, and I don't know if there is a way to stop it doing that.</sup>

Comment: Thanks all; I didn't know the language law. (And I treat HTML as XML, which generally has tighter standards so I thought it would flag this.) I went with `refuteSubstring(">>", xml)`

Comment: I think `>` is allowed in text in HTML as well.

Comment: HTML permits all kinds of atrocities because of website developers using Notepad.exe

Answer (score 3):

`>` can appear as a text in XML elements, representing it as `&gt;` is not mandatory.

```bash
$ echo '<xml><oops></oops>></xml>' | xmllint -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml><oops/>&gt;</xml>
```